# Only allow api from external network

Tags: symfony, nginx

We're having a setup where our server, running a symfony2 application, is inside the client's network.
Is there a way to allow only the /api* path to be accessed from an external network (=the internet).
I'm assuming the best approach is by configuring nginx but i can only find blocking all or no url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
location /api/ {

    # Deny private IPv4 address spaces
    deny 10.0.0.0/8;
    deny 172.16.0.0/12;
    deny 192.168.0.0/16;

    allow all;
}
```

See http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpAccessModule for more information.

Comment: This got me going, i also wasn't aware i could add multiple locations.